# Leaflet update getcenter coordinates

Tags: leaflet

I am bringing in leaflet routing control into my map and I would like to have the route icons show up in the center of the current view. using the code below I can get the icons to show up at the center of the inital view but I cannot find a way to get the center to update

Javascript:

```
    var route = L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: [
  L.latLng(map.getCenter()),
  L.latLng(map.getCenter())
  ]
});
```

JQuery:

```
$("#route-btn").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.leaflet-routing-container').is(':visible') ? route.removeFrom(map) : route.addTo(map);l
});
```

like most of the mistakes I make it is probably something simple, any help would be welcomed.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking. Are you talking about [this plugin](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine) or a different one? And what are you trying to do exactly (what do you mean by current view, for example). Overall difficult to answer without more explanation, and more code. A complete example would be useful.

Comment: I now see how unclear this request is. to clarify I am using the Leaflet Routing Machine plugin. when I fire getCenter, it adds points at the center of the initial view of the map. I would like the center to adjust based on where the user has moved the map to the new center of the map, not the original one.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`map.getBounds()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-get-methods) to obtain an [`LatLngBounds`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-getcenter) Object. This object has the method `getCenter()`, which will eventually give you an `LatLng` Object, which you can use for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `map.getCenter()` is only being called when you first declare `route`, and the waypoints retain those values afterward. So when you use `route.addTo(map)` in your function, `map.getCenter()` is not actually called again to reset them. To update the waypoints, you can use the `setWaypoints` method:

```
route.setWaypoints([L.latLng(map.getCenter()), L.latLng(map.getCenter())]);
```

Here's an example fiddle with a button that resets both waypoints to the current map center:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/pu39s9wn/